# How do I query status of update sticky depth in svn, set by --set-depth?

Tags: svn, depth, working-copy

So let's say I've changed my "[sticky depth](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.set_depth)" of a *working copy* directory to `'immediates'`, with

```
svn update --set-depth immediates my_dir
```

(Something related to [sparse dirs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).)

How do I determine this status of `my_dir`? Eg. I forgot which depth did I set, how can I check / test it? I've tried with `svn info -v .` in the parent with an `exclude` -d dir, but I could not see any info on it at all.

Comment: so `svn info -R --depth immediates` lists `exclude`-d folders or files, *too*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `svn info` is the right way. Just see at output, `Depth` key and compare values

```
>svn co URL --depth files
...
>svn info
...
Depth: files
...
```

and after update

```
>svn up --set-depth immediates
...
>svn info
...
Depth: immediates
...
```

Comment: I had a problem that I cannot call svn info in `excluded` directories without knowing their names first (and maybe I've forgot). But with your guidance I noticed that with `-R`, this can be achieved. Eg.: `svn info -R | grep -i "Depth" -B 8 | grep -i "Depth\|Path"`

Comment: @naxa, this is good, and thanks for teaching me the `grep -B` option.  I've tweaked your solution a little bit to future-proof it in case the length of `svn info` output changes: `svn info -R | grep '^Path\|^Depth' | grep '^Depth' -B 1`

Comment: This solution works very well, except for 'excluded' directories - `svn info -R` does not list them.  I exclude directories because they are very large and don't want to check them out just to find out which one has been excluded.  How do I list directories that have been excluded from the local workspace?

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is `svn info`, then look for `Depth: ...`.

Excluded directories are tricky.  They are excluded, i.e. not considered.  Some SVN clients will show excluded directories with `svn info -R`, but that is not reliable (e.g. SVN 1.6 does not show it).  Run `svn ls` (or `svn ls|grep '/$'`) to get a list of all directories and compare that list with the actual directories and the output of `svn st`.  If the directory is not present in your working copy and the status does not show it, then it is excluded.